# How can to keep the transparancy of a png image in Python using pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame, png, transparency

I am already struggling with this issue for quite some time, because I would like to keep the transparant background of a png image when using it in Python and pygame. If I use the code below, the transparant background becomes black. A screenshot is shown below. Note that I would like to be able to modify the colors of the image after loading, that's why I use the `image.putpixel` function.

```
import pygame
from PIL import Image

def pilImageToSurface(pilImage):  
    return pygame.image.fromstring(pilImage.tobytes(), pilImage.size, pilImage.mode).convert()

image = Image.open('creature1.png')
image.putpixel((10,10), (256,0,0))

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([100, 100])
screen.fill([10, 100, 10])

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    pygameSurface = pilImageToSurface(image)
    screen.blit(pygameSurface, pygameSurface.get_rect(center = (50,50)))
    pygame.display.flip()
    
pygame.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `convert_alpha()` instead of `convert()`:

<s>`return pygame.image.fromstring(pilImage.tobytes(), pilImage.size, pilImage.mode).convert()`</s>

```py
return pygame.image.fromstring(pilImage.tobytes(), pilImage.size, pilImage.mode).convert_alpha()
```

See [`pygame.image`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load):

> The returned Surface will contain the same color format, colorkey and alpha transparency as the file it came from. You will often want to call [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) with no arguments, to create a copy that will draw more quickly on the screen.
> For alpha transparency, like in .png images, use the [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) method after loading so that the image has per pixel transparency.

---

Furthermore it is not necessary to use PLI. Use [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) instead:

```py
pygameSurface = pygame.image.load('creature1.png').convert_alpha()
pygameSurface.set_at((10, 10), (255, 0, 0))
```